# Given the cartesian equation of a straight line $ y = mx+b$ , finding its " rotational " equation of the form $ x\cos(R)+ y \sin(R)= d$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry

Note : definitely, not HW, simply personal interest in rotations and linear transformations (cf. my previous questions)

---

The expression  $ x \cos(R)+ y \sin(R)= d$ ( with $d\geq 0$ ) is the equation of a vertical straight line $ x=d$ rotated $R$ radians counterclockwise ( about the origin $(0,0)$) .

Desmos construction : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g2dps3fccs

Note : in case $d\gt 0$ , this line " slides" on a circle of equation $ x^2 + y^2 = d^2$ ; if $d=0$ , the line turns around the origin.

Given the " rotational" equation $ x cos(R)+ y sin(R)= d$ , one can find the cartesian one  by solving for $y$ , thus obtaining :

$$ y = - \frac {\cos(R)} { \sin(R)} x + \frac {d} { \sin(R)} $$.

My question is how to go the other direction : given the equation $ y = mx +b$ , finding  the original distance $d$ and the rotation angle $R$ in order to rewrite the equation in the form

$$  x \cos(R)+ y \sin(R)= d$$

or, equivalently, in order to determine of which vertical line the given straight line is the image ( and under which rotation).

Comment: The hint is:  $\cos^2 R + \sin^2 R = 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar.  I find  $R= \arctan (m) - \pi/2$ and $d = (b) \sin(R) $ , but I cannot manage to make use of your hint. Would you please make it more explicit ( though explicit it may be in the absolute to the clear-sighted).   Desmos construction : <https://www.desmos.com/calculator/43jxtigzt9>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare $y=mx+b$ with the "rotational" equation $y = -\cot{R} \cdot x +\frac{d}{\sin{R}}$, to see that

$$m = -\cot{R}$$
$$b = \frac{d}{\sin{R}}$$

The first equation can be used to obtain $R$ from $m$, and then the second allows finding $b$ from $d$ and $R$.

Comment: Do you think there is no way to obtain $R$ without using an inverse trig function?

Comment: I think no. Even for the simple case of a line $y=mx$ you need an inverse trig function to find its angle from the positive x-axis. Going from unitless values to angles will (if I'm not mistaken) always require inverse trig functions.